# How to filter data by date range on mapbox GL JS?

Tags: javascript, filter, expression, mapbox-gl-js

I have some difficulties to implement this filter in mapboxGL-js

i have a vector tile layer that had some feature which include 2 properties 2 dates, startdate1 and enddate1 in string  with the following format yyyy-mm-dd
I'd like to filter only the features that are between my specific date range, startDate2, endDate2 with the same format

How can i get the date1 and date2, in order to  call the javascript function **Date.parse(date1)** in order to compare it against my startDate  ?

Id' like to apply the following condition in my filter to kepp only the features

```
Date.parse(startdate1)<= Date.parse(enddate2)  AND  Date.parse(enddate1) >= Date.parse(startdate2)
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 4):

The best way to handle this is by converting the date to timestamp (seconds since epoch). Then you can use the filter

```
[
     "all",     
    [">=", ['get', 'startDate1'], startDate2],
    ["<=", ['get', 'endDate1'], endDate2]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve it using something that I called a custom filter.
You must create a sintaxis that allow you to identify when filter with a date value is used (it can be any data type that MapBox does not support or a custom implementation).

Before you apply the filter to the desired layer you must to convert the custom filter to a MapBox expression, for me it was easy to use the match operator.
You must add listeners on the map instance to update the custom filters when the map is pan, zoomed or just moved because you require the rendered features and them are loaded only for the current viewport. I suggest the moveend event of the map.
You must create a kind of polling in order to know when the features are loaded I used the isSourceLoaded method in conjunction with the layer's source id. When you know the layer source is loaded you must use the querySourceFeatures method to get the features (it returns an array).

You must filter the features according to you custom filter and create a new filter expression that mapbox understand.
Note: You must filter the features by uniqueness due querySourceFeatures returns repeated values because features are retieved in multiple tiles sometimes.

It was no easy but it at the end the result looks good.
Good luck.